# A continuity problem

Tags: proof-verification, metric-spaces

> $\textbf{Problem:}$ Let $f:(X,d_1)\rightarrow (Y,d_2)$ a continuous function and $B \subseteq Y$. Consider the set : 
>   $$ A =\{ x \in X \vert d_2(f(x),Y-B)>0 \} $$
>   Prove that : $\forall x \in A : d_1(x,X-A)>0$.

My proof is based on demonstrating the following result:

> $\textbf{Lemma:}$ Let $(X,d)$ a metric space and $A\subseteq X$. Prove that the set : 
>   $$ A^{*}=\{ a \in X \vert d(a,A) >0 \} $$
>   is open.
>
> $\textbf{Proof:}$
>
> Let $a \in A^{*}$, so $d(a,A)>0$. Then exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that : 
>   $$ \dfrac{1}{n} < d(a,A) $$
>   Consider $r=d(a,A)-\dfrac{1}{n}>0$, let's prove that $B(a;r) \subseteq A^{*}$.
>
> Let $x \in B(a;r) \implies d(x,a)<r$, let's consider $b \in A$, so :
>
> $$ d(a,A) \leq d(a,b) \leq d(a,x)+d(x,b) <r+d(x,b) $$
>   $$ \frac{1}{n} < d(x,b) $$
>
> As this inequality is valid for any $b \in A$, we have to : 
>   $$ 0<\dfrac{1}{n} \leq d(x,A) $$
>   So $x \in A^{*}$ and so $A$ is open.

In the problem, the set :

$$A^{*}=\{y \in Y \vert d_2(y,Y-B)>0 \}$$

is open in $Y$. And $A=f^{-1}(A^{*})$ so $A$ is open in $X$($X-A$ is closed).

Then if $x\in A \implies x\notin X-A=\overline{X-A} \implies d_1(x,X-A)>0$

Is correct?, thanks!

Comment: More easily,  $A=f^{-1}(Y-\overline {Y-B})$ is open in $X$ because  $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Yes!, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed conclude by showing that $A$ is open. Here is an alternative proof of the fact that $A$ is open :

Consider $g(y)=d_1(y,Y-B)$. Then, for $y_1, y_2$ you have that for $z\in Y-B$,
$$g(y_2)=d(y_2,Y_B)\leq d(y_2,z)\leq d(y_2, y_1)+d(y_1,z)$$
so as it is true for all $z\in Y-B$ you have
$$g(y_2)-g(y_1)\leq d(y_1,y_2)$$
and $$|g(y_2)-g(y_1)|\leq d(y_1,y_2)$$
by symmetry.

So $g$ is $1$-Lipschitz, so continuous. Then, $A=(g\circ f>0)$ is open as an inverse image of an open set by a continuous function.

Comment: Thanks is a great proof!!. My way of proving the $\textbf{Lemma}$ is fine?

Comment: It is fine indeed.